# Checking for a string from a file(one line) in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of UK registrations(below),

```
list1 = [BD51SMR]
```

I also have a file, "complete file",

```
complete_file = open('Complete.txt', 'r')
```

Inside the file has a registration(the same ones as in the list) on one line, and it's associated speed on the next line.

I want to obtain the speed and not the registration from the file, so i want my code to work like below:

```
for line in complete_file:
    if line in list1:
        print('Line in list')
    else:
        print('Line not in list')
        #do something with the line(which should be the speed)
```

However both times it says "Line not in list", despite the fact that the complete file has the registration "BD51SMR", which is in the list! Can anyone help me?

Comment: 1. `list1` isn't a valid list. 2. Nor is it callable. 3. `line` probably has `'\n'` at the end.

Comment: do you just want to skip the first line of the file while reading the file?

Comment: Pretty much yeah, but this needs to be done multiple times i.e I have multiple sets of registrations and speeds in a file arranged like this:
reg
speed

reg
speed

etc on new lines for each reg/speed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
for line in complete_file.readlines():
    print "hey user. the this line is ",line
    if line.split(',')[0] in list1:
        print('Line in list')
    else:
        print('Line not in list')
        #do something with the line(which should be the speed)
```

Comment: It gives the error message "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I assumed you had comma-separated values

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it could be done.  This assumes the file doesn't have any structure beyond the Registration and Speed on adjacent lines.  If the file is setup with a Registration and Speed on every other line, you could optimize a bit by only checking every other line and skipping over the speed lines if the registration doesn't match.

```
with open('complete.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

registrations = ['BD03DF', 'FOHEFLS']
i = 0
speeds = {}
while i < len(lines):
    reg = lines[i].strip()
    i += 1
    if reg in registrations:
        speed = lines[i].strip()
        speeds[reg] = speed
        i += 1
```